# Making an array containing structures - C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, compiler-errors

Today I'm trying to implement a queue, but one that works with structures within arrays (I've always hated the C 'Array of Structs' terminology, as I am not trying to make that). However, when I try and do a basic initialization, I run into the compiler error as follows.

> "Request for member '****' in something not a structure or union. "

Here's my code, not much as of now.

```
//------------------------Preprocessor Instructions. ------------------------------------
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define MAX 128
#define BUFFER 120


//-------------------------Global Stuff -------------------------------------------------
int head=-1;
int tail=-1;    //Starting head and tail at -1. 

struct Entry{
    int Data;
    int Hops;   
}; 
struct Entry Queue[MAX];    //Queue made up of structs.

int visited[MAX];


//------------------------Function Definitions. -----------------------------------------
int QueuePush(struct Entry *q, int num);
int QueuePop(struct Entry *q);
int IsEmpty(struct Entry *q);


//------------------------Main. ---------------------------------------------------------
int main(void)
{
    int i;

    while(i<MAX){
        Queue.Data[i]=0;
        Queue.Hops[i]=0;
        i++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
        printf("Queue Data[%d] = %d \n", i, Queue[i].Data);
        printf("Queue Hops = %d \n", Queue[i].Hops);
    }


}
```

Am I making some scary, large error in the way I'm defining the array? Or is the issue syntactical? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write

```
Queue[i].Data = 0;
Queue[i].Hops = 0;
```

not

```
Queue.Data[i] = 0;
Queue.Hops[i] = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

In you initialization while loop, you have written `Queue.Data[i]` instead of `Queue[i].Data`.

Answer (score 2):

And another thing:

```
int i;

while(i<MAX){
    Queue.Data[i]=0;
    Queue.Hops[i]=0;
    i++;
}
```

Here `i` contains random number and this loop will not work, so you should write `int i = 0;` or use `for` instead of `while`.

Comment: Yeah, I caught that about 30 seconds ago haha. Thanks though!